# Eclipse: getting an error installing drjava

Tags: eclipse-plugin, drjava, eclipse-oxygen

I am currently trying to install DrJava plug-in in Eclipse Oxygen and I always get an error saying "could not find jar file" even though I opened it using the Install New Software in the Help menu...

I think I have tried everything I could but it does't seem to work...

or is there any better plugin in eclipse that has an interaction pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DrJava Plug-in](http://www.drjava.org/eclipse.shtml) for Eclipse is an Eclipse 2.x plug-in which are not supported anymore. Therefore, it is not possible to install the plug-in in a current version of Eclipse.

A very similar functionality is built in the Eclipse Java IDE as **[Java Scrapbook Page](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-view-scrapbook.htm)** (*File > New > Other...: Java > Java Run/Debug > Scrapbook Page*) and for debugging as [***Display* view**](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/display/ref-display_view.htm) (similar to select an expression in the Java editor and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or right-click and choose *Execute*).

In **Java 9**, there is also a so-called [**JShell**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm).

Comment: Is it the same as the interaction pane of DrJava and can it interact with other java files in a project?

Comment: Yes, in a _Java Scrapbook Page_ you can use classes of the project and the _Display_ view belongs to the debugging perspective and refers to the application that is currently being debugged.